# Setting "ViewModel" properties from "Model" class

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I am currently working on a project in Xamarin using the MVVM approach. I learned the basics from miscellaneous tutorials on youtube and the official Xamarin documentation. However, so far i have never seen an example that handles this particular question.

It may be that i have misunderstood some part of how the MVVM pattern should be used but if not, I would like to hear from someone else if they have any other solution to this.

I have got the basic binding between the ViewModel(.cs) and the View(.xaml).

Lets say that the "View" is a file called Profile.xaml and we have:

`<Label Text="{Binding Name}" />`

Which is bound to the "ViewModel", lets call it ProfileViewModel.cs which has the following property, and also implements the INotifyPropertyChanged:

`public string Name {get; set;}`

And of course the "Model" class which binds the two together with setting the BindingContext (lets say it implements ContentView and should be called Profile.xaml.cs):

```
private ProfileViewModel ViewModel;

public Profile() {
  BindingContext = ViewModel = new ProfileViewModel();
}
```

That sorts the binding between the "View" and the "ViewModel".

However, when i initialize the "View" (Profile.xaml) which is to be bound to the "ViewModel" (ProfileViewModel.cs), it is done through initializing the "Model" (Profile.xaml.cs) and I have not found an example yet that shows a good practice how to fill the ViewModel with already existing data.

Like in the example for this question, the "Name" may already exist in a database of some kind. And we initialize the whole Profile thing here by doing the following:

`<Profile Name="Napoleon" />`

Doing this the "Model" class (Profile.xaml.cs) also needs to have the following:
`public string Name {get; set;}`

And pass that string down to the "ViewModel" when the BindingContext is set:

```
BindingContext = new ProfileViewModel(){ 
  Name = this.Name 
}
```

However, i have come across situations where that sort of already existing data may come asynchronously or after the Profile "Model" has been Initialized. That has led me to the following solution. Implementing a set property that refers to the corresponding Property in the "ViewModel".

```
public string Name {
  get => ViewModel.Name;
  set => ViewModel.Name = value;
}
```

As i said, this works for me but I am really interested in other ideas how this can be solved or if I have got the MVVM pattern terribly wrong.

Comment: *.xaml.cs is not a model, it's a part of view (called _code-behind_). Actually, *.xaml and *.xaml.cs are compiled into a single class.

Comment: Ok thanks, any thoughts on the approach i used in my example?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up elements of MVVM.

`Profile.xaml` and `Profile.xaml.cs` are partial class declarations. They work together and compile into the same file. This is your view. As a general rule, there should be no logic in your xaml.cs file, but there are exceptions to this rule.

`ProfileViewModel.cs` is your view model. This handles all business logic and provides properties that the view binds to.

`Client.cs` would be an example of a model. Generally only public properties and no business logic exist in a model. Example follows:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

For your situation, you would use your view model to perform the web call and populate your model. then you would set your `ViewModel.Name` property to `Model.Name` and call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name))` or whatever your INotifyPropertyChanged method is called. This will tell the view that `Name` has changed and to update its representation.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out for me. Seems reasonable. However, if i was to set properties from the outside when Initializing, the client or the View, is a passthrough type of public property i gave as an example a good idea? Its just that in the application i am working with It quickly becomes a lot of web calls if they were to be done from each and every viewmodel.

Comment: so you're updating the model at the same time you're updating the property in the view model? if that's the case, then that is a fine use case. It guarantees the model is up to date in the event you want to send that back to the server to update the information.